# Newbie Questions on the Demarcation Problem

Tags: philosophy-of-science

**1) Is Astrology Science?**
Popper says science is distinguished from non-science by whether the subject in question is falisfiable.  So would Astrology and homeopathic medicine be considered science?  They both make falsifiable predictions.  The fact they have both been falsified, doesn't matter when deciding whether they are science?  Does this mean that anything manifestly absurd can be classed as science as long as it's falsifiable?  No regard for method, ability to provide an internally consistent theory, tractability etc...

**2) Popper's criticism of Kuhn's Demarcation Criterion.**
Why did Popper state (in describing Kuhn's demarcation criterion) that "In his view Kuhn's proposal leads to “the major disaster” of a “replacement of a rational criterion of science by a sociological one” ".
Can someone explain this to me why did Popper think that?  In what sense was Kuhn's demarcation criterion sociological?

**3) Do scientists really care about this?**
If something yields to science, scientists will work with it.  If it doesn't, they won't (?)

Comment: Hi, welcome to philosophy SE. Your question is too broad for this site. Please read general encyclopedic entries on the [demarcation problem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pseudo-science/), and try to narrow it down to something more specific

Comment: I would suggest, in slight tension with Conifold, that your second question would probably stand alone as a good kind of question to ask.  Perhaps if you were to make an edit to focus the form of your question more on that?

Comment: The available criteria for demarcation (like Popper's one) are abstraction. Clearly astrology is **not** a science because scientific community does not consider it any more scientific.

Comment: Kuhn has no demarcation criteria similar to Popper's one; what Popper reject is Kuhn's view about revolution as "motor of changes" in science because the "drivers" for changing paradigm process are not rational according to Popper.

Comment: Basically, "working science" does not care about demarcation. Obviously, what scientists consider as science changes in time: astrology is not, psycoanalysis... maybe ? string theory ? Thus, in principle, what has been "rejected" in the past may resurface in later time but, IMO, we have not significant examples of this process.

Comment: I would also suggest splitting this into multiple questions. There are at least two, possibly three, and maybe more, potentially interesting discussions to be had here. Possibly you could have a preamble that goes on each question, then a pointer to the first question in subsequent ones.

Comment: I recommend revising this post into at least three separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Astrology is not falsifiable.  It does not make falsifiable predictions, and your notion that it is making those predictions and they are already falsified is a misunderstanding of the system.  Because Astrological rules are wrapped around religious assumptions, if an astrologer finds out that the specific things they have predicted are contradicted, they blame themselves, and not the system.  There is no tipping point where the system itself takes any blame.

Kuhn's criterion for what is a science basically has to do with whether there is an agreed-upon paradigm.  To keep the language of blame from the first paragraph, the paradigm narrows down what blame goes to the system and what blame goes to the individual when there is a failure.

There is 'normal science', where blame naturally goes to the individual for making bad guesses.  But since the paradigm is an unwritten agreement, and no agreement is complete, there are criticisms built into the paradigm by the debate process that devolved upon it.  We can call those 'anomalies'.  Alongside normal science, there is a slowly accreting mass of evidence about the anomalies.

When the mass of problems that can be attributed to a genuine anomaly reaches an intolerable point, some new basic theory is proposed, which obsoletes a large quantity of normal science that was done to solidify the principle that needs changing. The people whose normal science is threatened defend it.  People whose normal science was judged incorrect may weigh in against them.

So this is an argument, and a huge quantity of social manipulation is actually part of the process.  Historically we see that the paradigm can be decided by sociological factors, like the religion or nationality of the people doing the negotiation.  From Popper's POV, that means the whole thing is basically sociological in nature.  The people who get to fuss with the paradigm and contribute to the negotiations that will excise the anomaly and choose a new principle are chosen by political means, by whose work dominates publication, for instance.  Respect by other people willing to work in the old paradigm is the measure of who sets the new one, and how far things move, not some theoretical standard, such as Popper's.  Scientific theories are judged by rules, but rules are judged by people.

Scientists don't generally take the philosophy of science at this level too seriously.  But they do need a basis for knowing what they can legitimately ignore.  And these principles of paradigmatic structure and falsifiable statements are actually useful.

You have to have some standards about what 'yielding' means, because science is hard.  Just because it isn't working, doesn't mean it isn't going to.

Clinical Psychology, for instance, has a very hard time staying a science.  Overall paradigms rise and fall in the span of a couple of decades because all the data is bad.  Humans are very hard to actually observe objectively.  What they teach you when you come in contains less genuinely valid theory and more a succession of mostly-failed theories and their limitations.  The verifiable successes are very few, and how you use them to reason about applications is troublingly hard to convey.

But the fact that the discipline as a whole keeps reconsolidating to the point they can make progress, means there is a science there, in the Kuhnian sense, even if what it says about most important things shifts every couple decades.  It is just hard.  Having a model of science that reflects that difficulty, and does not just impugn them/us all by comparing them to physics or biology, as idiots who should just give up and go home, is helpful.  Kuhn has had his effect, even if no one knows what he said.

They have the option of falling back into the state of early Freudianism, where the paradigm itself was so flexible that any criticism was unfalsifiable.  And then it would no longer be a science.  Popper has had his effect, even if they do not explicitly think about him.

You could just say "this field does not yield to science" and walk away.  But we haven't.  This is because we have a feeling for what rules are, and we are playing out what Kuhn said.  Having an overall observational structure based on the rise of early sciences to look at does help.

Comment: `Astrology is not falsifiable. It does not make falsifiable predictions.` In general, I don't believe this is true. A specific professional Astrologist would, for example, predict that his judgements of a persons personality given their birth date and time, gender, and perhaps a few other variables depending on the specific Astrologist, would pass certain tests.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that, while you can literally and easily falsify a *specific* Astrologers skills by devising these tests, all Astrologists are so different that Astrology fans would not consider this to have falsified the field as a whole. Which is... problematic.

Comment: @TKoL That means that it is not the Astrology doing the predicting.  The actual paradigm they share is so flexible that it does not give them guidance that makes them agree. As noted, if a physicist does things right often enough, and they don't work, he questions the rules -- Einstein exists.  In Astrology, that is not possible, the rules are too open.

Comment: `The actual paradigm they share is so flexible that it does not give them guidance that makes them agree` - yes, exactly. Astrology as an entire field is unfalsifiable by design. There's a constantly shifting goal post, which is why I think we've gone past the point of any researchers wanting to test it anymore.

Comment: @TKoL So, that being what I said the first time, you stated you disagreed, but you agree?  I did not say Astrologers, I said Astrology...

Comment: You said "it does not make falsifiable predictions". What is Astrology but the practice of Astrologists? Astrologists, by and large, do make Barnum statements, but the ones that are not are falsifiable, and there's even an extent that the ones that are barnum statements are falsifiable too - I can detail how. This is the specific part I was disagreeing with. `Astrology is not falsifiable` is generally agreeable though, but not bcause of the unfalsifiable predictions.

Comment: What is physics but the practice of physicists?  Only something completely different, a paradigm with rules.  If a pysicist goes out and gets drunk and does his work wrong, that isn't physics.   I am not here to quibble with whether you can find ways to misinterpret what I said.  Be reasonable.

Comment: I don't think I am misinterpreting it. `It does not make falsifiable predictions.` I'm just disagreeing with this specific part of it.